# Join two sql queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql queries and would like to combine them into one.

This one basically "merges" two columns into one.

```
SELECT description

CASE 
    WHEN checkbox2 = '2' THEN '2'
    WHEN checkbox2 = '1' THEN '1'
    WHEN checkbox2 = '0' THEN '0'   
    WHEN checkbox1 = '1' THEN '1'
    WHEN checkbox1 = '0' THEN '0' END 'checkbox_merge',

FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table3 
    ON table2.id2 = table3.id2
ORDER BY table2.id2
```

This one takes two tables and pivots the names (A->D) and uses them as columns to draw a grid if you will.

```
SELECT description

  MAX(CASE WHEN column1 = 'A' THEN checkbox1 ELSE '-' END) 'A',
  MAX(CASE WHEN column1 = 'B' THEN checkbox1 ELSE '-' END) 'B',
  MAX(CASE WHEN column1 = 'C' THEN checkbox1 ELSE '-' END) 'C',
  MAX(CASE WHEN column1 = 'D' THEN checkbox1 ELSE '-' END) 'D',

FROM table1
JOIN table2
    ON table2.id = table1.id
WHERE table2.id = var1 and table1.id = var1
GROUP BY description
```

So I would like to take the first query and use the `checkbox_merge` in place of the `checkbox1` in the second query.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  description,
  MAX(
    CASE 
        WHEN column1 = 'A' 
        THEN (
            CASE 
                WHEN checkbox2 = '2' THEN '2'
                WHEN checkbox2 = '1' THEN '1'
                WHEN checkbox2 = '0' THEN '0'   
                WHEN checkbox1 = '1' THEN '1'
                WHEN checkbox1 = '0' THEN '0'
            END
        ) 
    ELSE '-' 
    END
  ) 'A'

FROM 
  table1
JOIN table2
    ON table2.id = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 
    ON table2.id2 = table3.id2
WHERE 
    table1.id = var1
GROUP BY description
```

Comment: also i removed `table2.id = var1` since its the same condition as `table1.id = var1` because the 2 table are joined by `id`

Comment: <3 fantastic. It works just great. A bit messy but hey... It works in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This would work on SQL Server, not sure about MySQL.  Simply nest the first query in the second, similar to this mockup:

```
SELECT description

  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.column1 = 'A' THEN t1.checkbox_merge ELSE '-' END) 'A',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.column1 = 'B' THEN t1.checkbox_merge ELSE '-' END) 'B',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.column1 = 'C' THEN t1.checkbox_merge ELSE '-' END) 'C',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.column1 = 'D' THEN t1.checkbox_merge ELSE '-' END) 'D',

FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN checkbox2 = '2' THEN '2'
            WHEN checkbox2 = '1' THEN '1'
            WHEN checkbox2 = '0' THEN '0'   
            WHEN checkbox1 = '1' THEN '1'
            WHEN checkbox1 = '0' THEN '0' 
        END as [checkbox_merge],
        table2.id2 as [id]
    FROM table2 
    LEFT JOIN table3 
        ON table2.id2 = table3.id2
    ORDER BY table2.id2) 
as  t1
JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = var1 and t1.id = var1
GROUP BY t2.description
```

Comment: you're welcome.  Don't forget to mark as solution for others to use.  Also post back your edits, so the example is complete.